# Installing SASS through my terminal on my MAC -newbie

Tags: ruby, bash, installation, sass

I have done multiple searches for installing SASS through my terminal on my Mac, when I write the command `gem install sass`, it tells me

> -bash: $: command not found"

so I tried the alternative `sudo install` process. My result is

> -bash: $: command not found".

Am I missing something here?

Sorry for the dumb question. I'm just a web designer/developer trying to learn SASS, I did get a response once telling me this "WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.  To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.  Password:"(My typing was correct) so I type my PW. it then tells me it's the wrong PW.  -  I have one PW on this machine. What am I doing wrong?

I did get this error message after a third try " You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:~ JHess$ "

Do I not have the right permissions set up to perform the SASS install? I found a similar question on Stack regarding this issue - and it told me to install RVM. What exactly is RVM? Is it some type of bundled package?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I just attended a web conference in VA, "ConvergeRVA" and just recently graduated college, I'm not a seasoned vet like most peeps on here. But I would love to start learning SASS.

Note: I am running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Sass you need Ruby installed. The error messages shows you have an old version 1.8.7
Update to a current version using RVM.

> RVM is a command-line tool which allows you to easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments

Copy and paste this into your terminal.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

look at http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm to learn how to use it.

After this is done try `gem install sass` again

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed Mac OS X Command Line Tools. It can be found at:

> Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tool

Download & Install it, and restart the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For me to be able to install Xcode 5, I need version 10.8 or higher, I'm still running 10.7.5. Is there an alternative to installing Mountain Lion just to get Xcode 5? If not, I'l do what I have to do, just thought it would be an easier process to installing SASS.

Comment: I downloaded an older version of Xcode with command line tools, restarted my terminal, and still get the same message of "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory." Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. may have to have someone who is more savvy in this area help me out. Any other advice you could lend @ShivanRaptor ? I went and registered as an Apple dev to get the older version so I know it's legit. Just not sure what I'm missing here.